# Jaxb and namespace of inner element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I met a problem that looks simple but not obvious to solve.

I have 2 packages with classes marshalled to xml with different namespaces. One class is container for others.

```java
package namespace1;

@XmlRootElement(name = "container", namespace = "urn:nmsp:container:001.02")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
public class Container {
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "messages")
    private List<Message> messages;
}
-------------------------------------------

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Message", propOrder = {
        "document"
})
public class Message {
    @XmlElement(name = "Document", namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:001", required = true)
    protected Document document;
}
-------------------------------------------

package-info.java
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "urn:nmsp:container:001.02",
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        xmlns = {
                @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "urn:nmsp:container:001.02", prefix = "")
        })
package namespace1;
```

and

```java
package namespace2;

@XmlRootElement(name = "document", namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:001")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Document {
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private String id;
}

package-info.java
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:001",
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        xmlns = {
                @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:001", prefix = "")
        })
package namespace2;
```

What I would like to get is:

```xml
<container xmlns="urn:nmsp:container:001.02">
    <name>Hello</name>
    <messages>
        <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:001">
            <id>ID1</id>
        </Document>
    </messages>
</container>
```

But what I get is:

```xml
<container xmlns="urn:nmsp:container:001.02" xmlns:ns2="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:001">
    <name>Hello</name>
    <messages>
        <ns2:Document>
            <ns2:id>ID1</ns2:id>
        </ns2:Document>
    </messages>
</container>
```

Marshalling code is:

```java
Container conxml = new Container("Hello");
conxml.setMessages(List.of(new Message(new Document("ID1")))));
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Container.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
QName _Conxml_QNAME = new QName("urn:nmsp:container:001.02", "container");
JAXBElement<Container> conxmlJAXBElement = new JAXBElement<>(_Conxml_QNAME, Container.class, null, conxml);
marshaller.marshal(conxmlJAXBElement, writer);
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

Almost all solutions suggest to fix it with package-info.java but it doesn't help practically.
Can you please give me a hint where I am doing it wrong?

The link to maven project: [JaxbTest.7z](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fbhRO_tfF6-dVT5h7xVA--LN36ol-58q/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two XML files you give are equivalent, your choice of namespace declaration is a question of taste. The prefixes you set in the `@XmlNs` annotations are taken into account, when choosing the prefix for each namespace. However, JAXB RI at least, does not redefine them mid-document.

If you want to more directly intervene in the way the XML is generated, you need to add additional components between JAXB and the `Writer`. E.g. you can use StAX and marshall your document to an [XMLStreamWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html) like this one (the `IndentingXMLStreamWriter` comes from TXW2, a dependency of JAXB RI):

```java
   private static class RedefineNsXmlStreamWriter extends IndentingXMLStreamWriter {
      @Override
      public void writeStartElement(String prefix, String localName, String namespaceURI) throws XMLStreamException {
         final String known_prefix = getNamespaceContext().getPrefix(namespaceURI);
         super.writeStartElement(XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX, localName, namespaceURI);
         if (!XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX.equals(known_prefix)) {
            super.writeNamespace(XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX, namespaceURI);
         }
      }
      @Override
      public void writeNamespace(String prefix, String namespaceURI) throws XMLStreamException {
         // Ignore it
      }
      public RedefineNsXmlStreamWriter(XMLStreamWriter out) {
         super(out);
      }
   }
```

Then you create an `XMLStreamWriter` capable of writing to the `Writer` and serialize:

```java
final XMLStreamWriter xmlWriter = new RedefineNsXmlStreamWriter(XMLOutputFactory.newFactory()//
                                                                                .createXMLStreamWriter(writerCont));
marshallerCont.marshal(conxmlJAXBElement, xmlWriter);
```

Of course the `RedefineNsXmlStreamWriter` get more complicated once you take into account all cases, but it works for your example.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much, Piotr!